# Most efficient htaccess rule(s) for redirecting multiple domains and URIs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We are consolidating 3 domains under a single primary domain (oldsite1.com, oldsite2.com, primarysite.com). The content from the old domains has been reproduced on the primary domain, but has new paths. The two old domains will have their DNS records updated so they point to the server of the primarysite.com domain, and that server will be configured to accept inbound traffic for the two old domains. Redirection will occur using an .htaccess file on the primarysite.com account. There are approximately 160 "path" redirection rules.

So, our redirection has 2 parts:

1. 301 Redirect traffic for www.oldsite1.com and www.oldsite2.com to www.primarysite.com
2. 301 Redirect specific paths to new paths.

My question: Which is more efficient, individual RewriteCond rules for each of the 160 paths, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old/path/to/page.html$ http://www.primarysite.com/new/path/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^old/path/to/otherpage.html$ http://www.primarysite.com/another/new/path/ [L,R=301]
```

Or, is it better to do a single RewriteCond to handle both domains, followed by 160 individual RewriteRules, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.primarysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.primarysite.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^old/path/to/page.html$ http://www.primarysite.com/new/path/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^another/path/to/different/page.html$ http://www.primarysite.com/some/other/new/path [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is better as it is lesser code in .htaccess:

```
# redirect specific paths to new server and new path
RewriteRule ^old/path/to/page\.html$ http://www.primarysite.com/new/path/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^another/path/to/different/page\.html$ http://www.primarysite.com/some/other/new/path [L,R=301,NC]

# else if primary domain is not primarysite then redirect to primarysite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?primarysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.primarysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Any idea what the impact on SEO would be of having the referrer receive 2 sequential 301s?

Comment: That's pretty efficient and works well for my case. As long as the paths from the old sites are unique (which in this case they are), this is as good a solution as I think there is. Marked as the answer. Thanks!